# unable to fetch temperature data in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using this code to fetch temperature data from api.forecast.io but unable to do so. here is my code

```js
$(function () {

$('#container').highcharts({
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'New Delhi'
    },

    xAxis: {
     title: {
      text: 'Days'
     },
     type: 'datetime',
    },

    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature (°C)'
        },
        
        plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
    },

    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: '°C'
    },
 
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
       name: 'Daily Temp',       
       pointStart: Date.now(),
       pointInterval: 24*60*60*1000,
    data: []
    }]

  });

});

$.ajax({
 url: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/87a7dd82a91b0b765d2576872f2a3826/53.479324,-2.248485",
 cache: false,
 jsonp: "callback",
 dataType: "jsonp",
 success: function(chart) {

  var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();
    
   
 for(var i=0; i<chart.daily.data.length; i++)
 {
  myChart.series[0].data.push(chart.daily.data[i].temperature); 
 }
 }
 });
```

i am simply fetching data from using the api but when i plot the chart, there is no data. can someone help me? if you think my api url is incorrect then please suggest any other api through which i can fetch daily temperature data for a particular city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

1) You are not telling the chart to plot the data.

You are setting the data array after the chart is rendered, which will not not plot the data - it will just append the data to the object.

You can fix this by building a data array in your for loop, and then after the loop, using the highcharts api `setData()` call.

2) There is no attribute "temperature" in the data set. There is temperatureMax and temperatureMin.

Example:

```
var myChart = $('#container').highcharts();
var chartData = [];

for(var i=0; i < chart.daily.data.length; i++)
{
  chartData.push(chart.daily.data[i].temperatureMax); 
}

myChart.series[0].setData(chartData);
```

Updated Fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ybxa83px/

Comment: thanx it is working. can you please tell me how do i get to know about the variables like temperatureMax or temperature. how did you find that temperature is not defined in data set?

Comment: This line: console.log(chart); outputs the contents of the returned array to the javascript console. Open your console, refresh the page, and you can click through and see the elements.

Comment: ok. Great but where do i see this? Where to find the console. I am kind of new to highcharts so please bear with me.

Comment: The console isn't a Highcharts thing, it's part of your web browser. How to open it depends on your browser - I use firefox, and the firebug plugin.